# Mongoddb return _id after insert document

Tags: java, mongodb

I insert a document in MongoDB by using Java:

```
BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
    document.put("Atmospheric_Pressure", Atmospheric_Pressure);
    document.put("Humidity", Humidity);

    collection.insert(document);

    System.out.println(document);
```

The insert is working, I checked into the collection and it was ok. The System.out gave me the follwing result:

```
{ "Atmospheric_Pressure" : "3" , "Humidity" : "3" , "_id" : { "$oid" : "539d964070d2dfc425fc06a0"}}
```

My question is how can I get only the ID? I need only the value of the third item.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by calling `document.getObjectId("_id")`.

This will return you an object of type [`ObjectId`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/index.html?org/bson/types/ObjectId.html). If you just want to have the string value, you can proceed by calling `toString()` on the returned object ID.